# Edit apk without android stud

Tags: android, apk

is it possible to edit a file in apk (like in 7zip, not android stud.)?
If yes, after i edited the file the apk won't install on my mobile.
I tried to edit it in 7zip, android stud. (apk won't build) and apktool.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well .. I am not sure if I really understand your question ... but If you are asking about editing the apk files .. then yes you can edit them easily  ... if you are using a windows you can use Apk easy tool .. here is the link :
https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-windows-apk-easy-tool-v1-59-2-2021-04-03.3333960/

if you prefer editing the apk file using your phone ... you can use Apk editor pro or MT Manager for more advanced features.

Comment: Your question mainly consists of a link that can stop working at any time. Please always write an answer in a way that it can answer the question without having to use external sites, e.g. cite relevant parst form the linked web site.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).